# How to add the css properties to an image in ImageResourceCell of CellTable

Tags: css, gwt, celltable, clientbundle

I created a CellTable with image column in `GWT`. Image is added through `ImageResource .

```
private Column<DocList, ImageResource> statusColumn;
private final Resources resources = GWT.create(Resources.class);
final String STATUS_COLUMN = "Status";
statusColumn = buildStatusColumn();

private Column<DocList, ImageResource> buildStatusColumn() {
    statusColumn = new Column<DocList, ImageResource>(
            new ImageResourceCell()) {
        @Override
        public ImageResource getValue(DocList object) {
            return resources.draft();
        }
    };
    statusColumn.setDataStoreName(STATUS_COLUMN);
    return statusColumn;
}

public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
    @Source("draft.png")
    ImageResource draft();
}
```

But the problem is that I want to change some css properties of the image, for example, size or `cursor="pointer"` for click event, but I don't know how. In Firebug there is a default size.
How to add css to image done by `ImageResource` in GWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Column` has a method called [`getCellStyleName()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/Column.html#getCellStyleNames%28com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context,%20T%29).

You can override this method and return a style that reflects the image you use

```java
@Override
public String getCellStyleName()
{
    return resources.draft().getName();
}
```

Then you could create a style in your sheet like this:

```css
.draft img {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: ...;
    height: ...;
}
```

Comment: I did this, but nothing changed. There is no error, but image style is the same

Comment: @user3387259 Can you verify (using Firebug) that the cell actually has the style name you assigned and that it contains an `img` element?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Baz. Now it works!! I just run my project several times and css finally attached!))

Comment: @user3387259 Excellent :)